# How do I write the selenium IDE test case for CAPTCHA images?

Tags: selenium-ide

I am working on Selenium IDE for writing the test cases for a registration form. The registration form has a CAPTCHA image so I am not able to proceed with the automation, What could be the best solution to go ahead with? If I can provide a break point and let the user type it manually, then what is the command for carrying out that action? What are the best possible solutions with the complete commands>?

Answer (score 7):

Fun Fact: When you can't automate it, the CAPTCHA is doing it's job. :>

Answer (score 4):

**Solution # 1**
Temp remove the CAPTCHA for the testing

**Solution # 2** (As you mention to provide a break point to insert captcha manualy)
1. Try prompt a text box for user to key in the captcha, and store in variable
example:
storeEval | prompt("Enter Captcha:") | varName

1. Then type the varName text in to your captcha text box
   example 
   type | id=CaptchaText | ${varName}

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is by just add 3 pause saying something like " Write Captcha Manually" with 9 second each. see example below:

Command : Pause
Target: 9999
Value: "Write Captcha Manually"

This will give you time to type the captcha.